# Selecting Rows based on a Cell's Value and Pasting them into a New sheet excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy entire rows based on the value in column A. The criteria will be yesterdays date. The macro needs to stay dynamic as everyday this macro will be run and using the day before's data. Here is what I have so far:

```
    Sub SelectRowsByDate()

    Dim WS1 As Worksheet
    Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test")

    Dim YesterdayDate As Date
    Dim loopCounter As Long
    YesterdayDate = Date - 1
    For loopCounter = 1 To Rows.Count
       If Cells(i, 1).Value = YesterdayDate Then
       Rows(i).Select

    End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't use [macros] for MS Office or VBA. [macros tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info)

Comment: Can you specify what's not working?

Comment: Yea I am getting stuck on the If statement. I also was not sure how after selecting the row to copy it over to a different sheet. 
Thanks!

Comment: Also if it helps the data I'm looking at has a header in cell A1 and then after that it will contain lets the like 20 cells with yesterdays date. But when I want to run the report tomorrow there might be 21 rows with the date I'm looking for.

Comment: You're mixing variables... loopCounter and i. Either use i=1 or cells(loopCounter,1)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code.  The first is that you need a next for every For.  You could try this:

```
Sub improved()

Dim irow As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim dDate As Date

x = 1
For irow = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1))
    dDate = Cells(irow, 1).Value
    If dDate = Date - 1 Then
        Debug.Print Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow, 1).Value
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow, 1).EntireRow.Copy
        Sheet2.Range("A" & x).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

It uses the EntireRow function, which is what you need.  You'll need to change the sheet names you're working on to Sheet1 and Sheet2.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

lets make it in steps as an ideas in a task i made before .

1- in your Macro function use something like this to loop the main sheet and its delivered data

```
For I = 4 To Worksheets(Isheet).Rows.Count
  If Worksheets(Isheets).Cells(I, 7).Value <> "" Then
    For N = 1 To Worksheets.Count-1
        If Worksheets(N).Name = Worksheets(Isheets).Cells(I, 7).Value Then
          // Insert the Current row in this sheet 
          Exit For
        End If
    Next N
    If N >= Worksheets.Count 
      // in this case the is new, so here will make a new Sheet for his rows and then insert this row in it.
      Worksheets.Add ,,
    End IF
  End If
Next N
```

any stopping in the task comment me.

Nice wishes to you,